# Finite imensional subspaces of $L^\infty.$

Tags: convex-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

This is the question I had meant to ask when I asked [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94661/finite-dimensional-subspaces-of-l1): Is there a concise characterization of finite dimensional subspaces of $L^\infty?$ (that's what the discussion with @fedja was really about...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's much easier and more standard than finite-dimensional subspaces of $L^1$.  The answer is all norms in finite dimensions, or in the unit ball picture, all centrally symmetric convex bodies.  Every polytope is a slice of an $n$-cube, so clearly you get all of those.  But then the Banach-Alaoglu theorem in this case lets you take limits; the space of $d$-dimensional subspaces of $L^\infty$ is compact.  The same argument works for $\ell^\infty$, which embeds in $L^\infty$.

In fact in the case of $\ell^\infty$ you can simply explicitly make every centrally symmetric convex body in $d$ dimensions as an intersection of countably many antipodal pairs of half spaces, and take the corresponding embedding in $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: You mean "every centrally-symmetric polytope", I assume. Is that obvious?

Comment: If a centrally symmetric $d$-polytope has $2n$ facets, then it is a slice of an $n$-cube, which also has $2n$ facets.  You can construct the linear map directly from the hyperplanes of opposite pairs of facets.  The word "obvious" doesn't do much for me, but let's say that it's an exercise.


Comment: Greg said it right.  Every centrally-symmetric polytope embeds isometrically into the much smaller space $c_0$; in fact, a finite dimensional Banach space embeds isometrically into $c_0$ if and only if its unit ball is a polytope.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. All finite dimensional Banach spaces.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask something slightly different?

Comment: That's what I thought. Why is that obvious?

Comment: Maybe I did (as you see I am not very with it;) In the alluded to discussion, the OP had asked for a family of functions with prescribed $2-$ and $1-$ norms, and with sup norm bounded by $1.$ As pointed out by @fedya, this last condition is the hard one (otherwise you construct a geodesic on the sphere in three dimensions and you are done), but the set of linear combinations of three given functions with sup norm $\leq 1$ appears to be an arbitrary convex centrally symmetric set (as you seem to confirm...) so...



Comment: Every separable Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_1$, hence every separable reflexive Banach space embeds isometrically into $\ell_\infty$, which in turn embeds isometrically into $L_\infty$.

Comment: Or: every separable Banach space embeds isometrically into $C[0,1]$, which clearly embeds isometrically into $L_\infty$.  